# regex assistance for validating an email address

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to validate an email field. I took this regex from somewhere on here for and I used it on another form I made and it works fine. Yet when I use it now its not matching.

All I am trying to do is to check the email and if it is good then log it in the proper field in the db.

For the sake of not pasting a bunch of stuff... I have stripped out the problem lines and going to pseudo code next few lines.

Essentially, vars are these:

```
$theEmail = $_post email from first page here
$regEx ='#^[a-z0-9.!\#$%&\'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@([0-9.]+|([^\s]+\.+[a-z]{2,6}))$#si';
```

and my php is this

```
//essentially other field validation will go here...for now testing only empty.
    if(!empty($theEmail)){
        if (preg_match($regEx, $formEmail)) {
            //send it through to db.

        } else { //error stuff here }
    }
```

essentially, this never comes true. The email never validates no matter what I do and as I said I wrote another more complicated form that validates data just fine

Not sure what is going on.

Comment: The regex is pretty hosed. What do you expect it ti match?

Comment: Your regex has a hyphen that needs to be escaped at `...+-/=...`. That probably won't fix it outright, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/^[a-z0-9.!\#$%&\'*+-=?^_{|}~]+@([0-9.]+|([^\s]+\.+[a-z]{2,6}))$/`

I removed the first `#` and ending `#si`, and took out the `/` from the `=` since it was giving me problems. This generates a match on my e-mail address here:

```
<?
$theEmail = 'me@davebel.com';
$regEx ='/^[a-z0-9.!\#$%&\'*+-=?^_`{|}~]+@([0-9.]+|([^\s]+\.+[a-z]{2,6}))$/';
print_r(preg_match($regEx, $theEmail));
?>
```

Though this regex is very complex for something like e-mail validation- I would recommend trying to refine it and fine-tune it before putting it into production.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use `filter_var` instead.

```
if (filter_var($theEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  //send it through to db.
} else {
  //error stuff here
}
```

Comment: regEx, lord knows ive tried but its like rocket science to me. This works...its new right...is this phps way to test stuff without regex?

Comment: @somdow `filter_var()` is fairly new indeed. It exists since PHP 5.2. For more information, check out the list of available filters here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

Answer (score 0):

With email validation there are simple solutions that catch 99 % of all mistakes and complex solutions that might catch a tenth of a percent more, yet be unreadable.

Go the easy route and just check for something like

```
.+@.+\..+
```

Yes, it will allow an email address like `a@b.c` but that's probably a smaller price to pay than a user who cannot register because your 500-character regex has a mistake in it somewhere, rejecting a valid address.

Comment: It will also accept `@@@..` so perhaps some simple additional constraints would be useful.

Comment: Sure, you can use `[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+` instead. My point is that I see such validation things as very simple ways of making sure they didn't write utter nonsense there. This means it just needs to catch the most obvious mistakes while filling something out. The more complex you make the regex (while trying to mold it perfectly to the specification of the input) the likelier you introduce a tiny mistake which might make a user suffer. Maybe you only thought of TLDs with 3 or 4 chars (I know they used 6 here, but that excludes all internationalised ccTLDs, for example).

Comment: I'd rather have *some* bogus data from users who then won't even get the verification mail (thus rendering the account unusable) than risk alienating users by potentially rejecting valid data by mistake just because I made something more complex which could have been simple.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try! hopefully it will resolve your query, although there are infinte regulare expressions for email

```
^[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,})$
```

For testing visit
[Regular Expression Tester](http://www.regexpal.com/)